# Tomcat - demand CLIENT-CERT only on certain pages but demand SSL in all pages

Tags: tomcat, ssl, client-certificates

I am currently forcing SSL on my web app using the following security constraint on its web.xml:

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

Now I have implemented client certificate login, I added

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

This allows me to retrieve the client certificate from the web app and use it to log in the client.

But there are public pages that do not require authentication where I stil would like to force SSL (It is an official site so whatever you are seeing published on it, private or not, it is good to have a CA validating the server certificate).

In short: I do not want tomcat requesting a client certificate for these public pages, but I want to request it on the private ones. How can I set my web.xml / server.xml configuration to allow this?

Comment: How about just not hosting anything on port 80? Then only protect the pages that require authentication with a `<security-constraint>`.

Comment: If I don't host anything on port 80, how can I redirect `http://example.com/whatever` to `https://example.com/whatever`?

Comment: So, change your `<url-pattern>` from `/*` to something more specific.

Comment: No, I am not explaining myself correctly: I want to *force* SSL on `/*`, but not force neither request *client* authentication. I want to *request* client authentication on a single page. Is that possible?

Comment: What does your `<Connector>` configuration look like?

Comment: `<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>`

Comment: `<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="want" maxThreads="150" port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>`

Comment: Like I said I have also tried different combinations with `clientAuth="false"`. None seems to work

Comment: Hmm... I was going to suggest `clientAuth="want"` but you've already got that...

Comment: Can you head-over to the Tomcat users' list? There are a greater number of helpful experts over there than here on SO.

Comment: I will. Thank you :-)